# excel multiple average in single column

Tags: excel

I would like help with my excel spreadsheet. 
In one column I have product number in the second column there is execution time:
A   B      C
1  0:17    
1  0:18
1  0:19   0:18
2  1:12
2  1:12
2  1:13  1:12:6
3  0:45   0:45
I would like to make an average for every product in the next column (column C).
I have tried:

```
=IF(A1=A2;0;AVERAGE(IF(A:A=A1;B:B)))
```

but it fails miserably.
So my question is how can I automatically select a range in A with the same number to make an average and display it at the end of that product?

EDIT:I use excel 2003.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way will work but the formula needs to be "array entered". Better to use `AVERAGEIF` function like this in C1 copied down

`=IF(A1=A2;"";AVERAGEIF(A$1:A1;A1;B$1:B1))`

For Excel 2003 or earlier versions you can either use this "array formula" (essentially what you had originally)

`=IF(A1=A2;"";AVERAGE(IF(A$1:A1=A1;B$1:B1)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> then copied down

....or use this non-array version

`=IF(A1=A2;"";SUMIF(A$1:A1;A1;B$1:B1)/COUNTIF(A$1:A1;A1))`

Comment: It still doesn't work.I have excel 2003.Is AVERAGEIF supported? Won't that code make all the product in one average?

Comment: No, you can't use AVERAGEIF in Excel 2003, I'm adding some suggestions for 2003 - it should work as required

Comment: @user3713940 - see revised answer

Answer (score 0):

## Formula:

`=IF(COUNTIF($A2:$A$65535,$A1)=0,SUMIF($A$1:$A1,$A1,$B$1:$B1)/COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1),"")`

Paste this formula into C1 and fill or copy down to the bottom of the data.

This formula also accounts for unsorted data.

Answer (score -1):

You can use AVERAGEIF or AVERAGEIFS to include a condition or multiple conditions in average calculation.

First of All copy and paste column A in a new column ( Exa , Column F ) and then Remove duplicates.

=AVERAGEIF("A:A",F1,"B:B")

Comment: `AVERAGEIF` is not available in Excel 2003.